# SVG изображение встроено в CSS с помощью background-image

Tags: css, html5, svg, filter

Вот  SVG анимация при наведении на изображение.
Есть ли способ, где я могу избежать написания кода SVG дважды?

```css
body {
  background-color: #181818;
}

a {
  -webkit-transition: all .3s ease;
  -moz-transition: all .3s ease;
  -o-transition: all .3s ease;
  transition: all .3s ease;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  display: inline-block;
}

#twitter {
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg style='fill: %23777' enable-background='new 0 0 612 612' version='1.1' viewBox='0 0 612 612' xml:space='preserve' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'%3E%3Cpath d='m612 116.26c-22.525 9.981-46.694 16.75-72.088 19.772 25.929-15.527 45.777-40.155 55.184-69.411-24.322 14.379-51.169 24.82-79.775 30.48-22.907-24.437-55.49-39.658-91.63-39.658-69.334 0-125.55 56.217-125.55 125.51 0 9.828 1.109 19.427 3.251 28.606-104.33-5.24-196.84-55.223-258.75-131.17-10.823 18.51-16.98 40.078-16.98 63.101 0 43.559 22.181 81.993 55.835 104.48-20.575-0.688-39.926-6.348-56.867-15.756v1.568c0 60.806 43.291 111.55 100.69 123.1-10.517 2.83-21.607 4.398-33.08 4.398-8.107 0-15.947-0.803-23.634-2.333 15.985 49.907 62.336 86.199 117.25 87.194-42.947 33.654-97.099 53.655-155.92 53.655-10.134 0-20.116-0.612-29.944-1.721 55.567 35.681 121.54 56.485 192.44 56.485 230.95 0 357.19-191.29 357.19-357.19l-0.421-16.253c24.666-17.593 46.005-39.697 62.794-64.861z'%3E%3C/path%3E%3C/svg%3E");
}

#twitter:hover {
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg style='fill: %2300aced' enable-background='new 0 0 612 612' version='1.1' viewBox='0 0 612 612' xml:space='preserve' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'%3E%3Cpath d='m612 116.26c-22.525 9.981-46.694 16.75-72.088 19.772 25.929-15.527 45.777-40.155 55.184-69.411-24.322 14.379-51.169 24.82-79.775 30.48-22.907-24.437-55.49-39.658-91.63-39.658-69.334 0-125.55 56.217-125.55 125.51 0 9.828 1.109 19.427 3.251 28.606-104.33-5.24-196.84-55.223-258.75-131.17-10.823 18.51-16.98 40.078-16.98 63.101 0 43.559 22.181 81.993 55.835 104.48-20.575-0.688-39.926-6.348-56.867-15.756v1.568c0 60.806 43.291 111.55 100.69 123.1-10.517 2.83-21.607 4.398-33.08 4.398-8.107 0-15.947-0.803-23.634-2.333 15.985 49.907 62.336 86.199 117.25 87.194-42.947 33.654-97.099 53.655-155.92 53.655-10.134 0-20.116-0.612-29.944-1.721 55.567 35.681 121.54 56.485 192.44 56.485 230.95 0 357.19-191.29 357.19-357.19l-0.421-16.253c24.666-17.593 46.005-39.697 62.794-64.861z'%3E%3C/path%3E%3C/svg%3E");
}
</style>
```

```html
<a id="twitter" href="#"></a>
```

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/50430277/7394871

Answer (score 3):

Известно, что если SVG изображение добавляется с помощью `background-image`, то оно теряет все преимущества формата SVG. В том числе, становится невозможно стилизовать изображение с помощью  правил CSS: `fill`, `stroke` и т.д.

Но есть решение этой проблемы:

Идея состоит в том, чтобы использовать возможность применения фильтра,  избежав тем самым, дублирования кода SVG. 
Вам просто нужно настроить различные значения, чтобы получить цвета, которые вы хотите.

```css
body {
  background-color: #181818;
}
a {
    transition: all .3s ease;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    display: inline-block;
}
#twitter {
    background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg style='fill: %2300aced' enable-background='new 0 0 612 612' version='1.1' viewBox='0 0 612 612' xml:space='preserve' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'%3E%3Cpath d='m612 116.26c-22.525 9.981-46.694 16.75-72.088 19.772 25.929-15.527 45.777-40.155 55.184-69.411-24.322 14.379-51.169 24.82-79.775 30.48-22.907-24.437-55.49-39.658-91.63-39.658-69.334 0-125.55 56.217-125.55 125.51 0 9.828 1.109 19.427 3.251 28.606-104.33-5.24-196.84-55.223-258.75-131.17-10.823 18.51-16.98 40.078-16.98 63.101 0 43.559 22.181 81.993 55.835 104.48-20.575-0.688-39.926-6.348-56.867-15.756v1.568c0 60.806 43.291 111.55 100.69 123.1-10.517 2.83-21.607 4.398-33.08 4.398-8.107 0-15.947-0.803-23.634-2.333 15.985 49.907 62.336 86.199 117.25 87.194-42.947 33.654-97.099 53.655-155.92 53.655-10.134 0-20.116-0.612-29.944-1.721 55.567 35.681 121.54 56.485 192.44 56.485 230.95 0 357.19-191.29 357.19-357.19l-0.421-16.253c24.666-17.593 46.005-39.697 62.794-64.861z'%3E%3C/path%3E%3C/svg%3E");
    filter:grayscale(100%) brightness(0.6);
}
#twitter:hover {
    filter:grayscale(0%);
}
```

```html
<a id="twitter" href="#"></a>
```

Comment: Alexandr_TT, привет, [вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1050748/svg-Как-скруглить-при-анимации-углы-иконки) для тебя..)))