# Как закруглить при анимации углы иконки гамбургера

Tags: javascript, css, svg, css-animation

Есть такой пример:

```js
document.querySelector('#svg').addEventListener('click', function() {
  [...document.querySelectorAll('.line')].forEach(s => {
    s.classList.contains('path-line') ?
      s.classList.remove('path-line') :
      s.classList.add('path-line');
  })
})
```

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  background-color: #272727;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

svg {
  background-color: black;
}

#path_line_3 {
  stroke-dasharray: 30 43;
  stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  transition: all .2s;
}

#path_line_1 {
  stroke-dasharray: 30 43;
  stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  transition: all .2s;
}

#path_line_2 {
  stroke-dasharray: 30 43;
  stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  transition: all .2s;
}

#path_line_2.path-line {
  stroke-dasharray: 0 30;
  stroke-dashoffset: 0;
}

#path_line_3.path-line {
  stroke-dasharray: 43.4 30;
  stroke-dashoffset: -30;
}

#path_line_1.path-line {
  stroke-dasharray: 43.4 30;
  stroke-dashoffset: -30;
}
```

```html
<svg id="svg" version="1.1" baseProfile="full" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="500" height="500" viewBox="0 0 50 50">
        <path id="path_line_1" class="line" d="M 10 10, 40 10, 10 40" stroke-linecap="round" fill="transparent" stroke="white " stroke-width="3" />

        <path id="path_line_2" class="line" d="M 25 25, 40 25" stroke-linecap="round" fill="transparent" stroke="white " stroke-width="3" />

        <path id="path_line_3" class="line" d="M 10 40, 40 40, 10 10" stroke-linecap="round" fill="transparent" stroke="white " stroke-width="3" />
        
    </svg>
```

Можно ли закруглить острые углы, отмеченные на картинке ниже.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Не сразу понял что нужно кликнуть.

За оформление соединения сегментов линий в SVG отвечает свойство `stroke-linejoin` оно может принимать такие-же значения как и `stroke-linecap`, который Вы уже использовали:

`bevel` | `miter` | `round`

---

Вам поможет  `stroke-linejoin="round"`

```js
document.querySelector('#svg').addEventListener('click', function() {
  [...document.querySelectorAll('.line')].forEach(s => {
    s.classList.contains('path-line') ?
      s.classList.remove('path-line') :
      s.classList.add('path-line');
  })
})
```

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  background-color: #272727;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

svg {
  background-color: black;
}

#path_line_3 {
  stroke-dasharray: 30 43;
  stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  transition: all .2s;
}

#path_line_1 {
  stroke-dasharray: 30 43;
  stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  transition: all .2s;
}

#path_line_2 {
  stroke-dasharray: 30 43;
  stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  transition: all .2s;
}

#path_line_2.path-line {
  stroke-dasharray: 0 30;
  stroke-dashoffset: 0;
}

#path_line_3.path-line {
  stroke-dasharray: 43.4 30;
  stroke-dashoffset: -30;
}

#path_line_1.path-line {
  stroke-dasharray: 43.4 30;
  stroke-dashoffset: -30;
}
```

```html
<svg id="svg" version="1.1" baseProfile="full" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="500" height="500" viewBox="0 0 50 50">
        <path id="path_line_1" class="line" d="M 10 10, 40 10, 10 40" stroke-linecap="round"  stroke-linejoin="round" fill="transparent" stroke="white " stroke-width="3" />

        <path id="path_line_2" class="line" d="M 25 25, 40 25" stroke-linecap="round" fill="transparent" stroke="white " stroke-width="3"  stroke-linejoin="round"/>

        <path id="path_line_3" class="line" d="M 10 40, 40 40, 10 10" stroke-linecap="round" fill="transparent" stroke="white " stroke-width="3"  stroke-linejoin="round" />
        
    </svg>
```

Comment: Благодарю.......